# basic app + express + mongodb + how to not use the port?

Tags: express, port

This is a basic app I have got that uses express for setting up routes and and also does some query on a mongo db

If I go to `http://localhost:8080/` whatever is in the views/hello.html will be displayed in the browser.
If i go to `http://localhost:8080/test` 'This is a test Page' will be displayed in the browser.

My question is why do I have to specify the port 8080 in the address? Or put another way how do I display what i want at this address `http://localhost/` without specifying the port?

I know I can change the port by changing the value of 8080 here

```
app.listen(8080);
```

basic app below:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/m101', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    //set up a route to go to the page http://localhost:8080/ to see 'This is a test Page' 
    app.get('/', function(req, res){


        db.collection('hw1_3').findOne(function(err, doc) {
             //do stuff here 

             return res.render('hello', { "name" : decrypted });
        });
    });

    //set up a route to go to the page http://localhost/test to see 'This is a test Page' 
    app.get('/test', function(req, res){
        return res.send('This is a test Page!!', 200);
    });

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default port for http traffic is 80. If you bind to any port other than 80, you need to specify the port in the URL. `app.listen(80)` will take care of your problem.

On Unixy systems, root (administrator) access is required to bind to any port less than 1024, so you'll have to run your server like `sudo node server.js` to get port 80. You should bind to a higher port (like 8080) in this case while developing on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty noob, but I'd say that `localhost:8080` displays in place of `www.somesite.com`. I wouldn't get too wrapped up in the port number. If you deploy it to heroku or something you wont see it.